# Problem to understand random variable : For example, $X(\omega )=1$ is really random ?

Tags: probability

I have difficulty to understand random variable. Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let say $\Omega =[0,1]$, $\mathbb P=m$ the lebesgue measure and $\mathcal F=\mathcal B_{[0,1]}$ the Borel $\sigma -$algebra. Let take for example, $X(\omega )=1$ or $X(\omega )=\omega $. In what is it random ? If I fix $\omega \in \Omega $, then $X(\omega )=\omega $ is know, and not unknow.

Other example, if I want a number in $[0,1]$. So, $X(\omega )=\omega $ should work. So if I fix $\omega $, I know $X(\omega )$... why is it random ? Also, if $Y$ is a uniform r.v. in $[0,1]$ don't we have that $X(\omega )=Y(\omega )=\omega $ a.s. ?

Comment: If $X(\omega )=\omega $ for all $\omega $ and $Y(\omega )=X(\omega )$ a.s., it's **impossible** to know $Y(\omega )$ for $\omega $ fixed. Notice that even if $Y(\omega )=1$ a.s., the function $Y$ can be **HORRIBLE**

Comment: the randomness is not in the mathematical formulism if not in what a probability distribution represent for us, in the real life. Every event have associated a probability, that is a number between zero and one, but what this number represent is up to us.

Comment: Absence of randomness in the human agreement of "none predictability" is not a mathematical notion. And BTW, the point of using random variables is that you don't generally know the sample space $\Omega$, so you don't know $\omega$ :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS: In my example with $X(\omega )=\omega $ on $([0,1],\mathcal B,m)$ we know everything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a perspective that was imparted to me by my thesis advisor: You have a function (i.e. $X$, the random variable) on a domain (i.e. $\Omega$, the sample space). It behaves just like all other functions you've ever encountered behave. The catch, though, is that you never really pick an individual $\omega$ and evaluate $X(\omega)$. Instead, Tyche, the Greek goddess of fortune, chooses an input $\omega$ for you, and she will make her choices according to the measure $\mathbb P$. Your task is to describe broadly what will happen to the outputs $X(\omega)$.

You're quite right that if you fix a particular $\omega \in \Omega$, then nothing is really random; you're just evaluating a function. The "random" component is the part where you surrender control over which particular $\omega$ you choose back to Tyche.

> Also, if Y is a uniform r.v. in [0,1] don't we have that X(ω)=Y(ω)=ω a.s. ?

Not necessarily; it depends on how $X$ and $Y$ map $\Omega$ onto the real number line. Consider this example, where the sample space is $\Omega = [0, 1]$ and the probability measure is the Borel / Lebesgue measure:
$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases} \omega, & 0 \leq \omega \leq 1 \\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$$Y(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1-\omega, & 0 \leq \omega \leq 1 \\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Both $X$ and $Y$ have an equally legitimate claim to the title "uniformly-distributed random variable on $[0, 1]$". Consider why; your only concern is the probability of $X$ or $Y$ being in particular regions after Tyche has chosen her input. The essential characteristic is that if you choose $a, b$ such that $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$, that $\mathbb P(a \leq X \leq b) = b-a$. It is also true that $\mathbb P(a \leq Y \leq b) = b-a$. Yet, it also happens to be true that $\mathbb P(X = Y) = 0$. Here's a third variable that has the same property:
$$Z(\omega) = \begin{cases} \omega, & 0 \leq \omega \leq 1 \text{ and } \omega \not \in \mathbb Q \\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Here, $Z$ again has just as much claim to be a "uniformly distributed variable on $[0, 1]$" as $X$ or $Y$ do. This function is not terribly well-behaved, since it has infinitely many discontinuities. Yet, all we care about are the distributions after $Z$ has done its mapping.

How $X$ maps the particular sample spaces onto $\mathbb R$ is not relevant; to characterize a random variable, your only concern is to characterize statements like $\mathbb P(a \leq X \leq b)$. There are many ways to accomplish this; an equivalent one would be to successfully characterize all statements like $\mathbb P(X \leq c)$. But the point is that you don't care about how the actual inputs are structured, and you don't care about how exactly they're mapped onto the reals by $X$; you only care about things like $\mathbb P(X \in A) = \mathbb P(\omega: X(\omega) \in A)$.

Comment: I like very much your answer. just a small question : for the expriment "talking a number randomly in $[0,1]$ : do you agree that $X(\omega )=\omega $ is the correct function ? Because, how can we describe a function if we don't know it ? (I don't really get this point).

Comment: To be honnest, I don't really see which function would describe  "choosing a number at random in $[0,1]$", because it could also be $Y$ rather than $X$, no ? Or why not $Z$ ? (but I don't think so).

Comment: "But the point is that you don't care about how the actual inputs are structured" : How can you don't care of the sample space ? It's the base to describe an experiment... I'm a bit confuse, sorry.

Comment: No, I would not agree that $X(\omega) = \omega$ is the "correct" function for "taking a number randomly in $[0, 1]$". As you referenced in your other comments, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ would all serve that role equally well; that's precisely my point. We don't care about the sample space because it's usually irrelevant. In probability, we use statements like, "Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with mean 10"; we don't explicitly discuss $\Omega$, and indeed many different choices for $\Omega$ (and corresponding maps $X$) would work equally well.

Comment: Of course, $\Omega$ does lurk in the background in a theoretical context. But even for a given experiment, there could be many suitable choices for $\Omega$. For example: in a coin flip, I could choose $\Omega$ to be the two-point set $\{H, T\}$ (corresponding measure $\mathbb P(H) = \mathbb P(T) = 0.5$); I could also choose $\Omega$ to be $[0, 1)$ with $\sigma$-algebra consisting of $[0, 1), [0, 0.5), [0.5, 1),$ and $\emptyset$ (equipped with Lebesgue measure). Neither of these are better to model a coin flip; they're just different.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992091/does-it-make-sense-to-evaluate-a-function-that-is-defined-almost-everywhere-fo/2992118#2992118) a question that is very related to this post . If you see the question and see the answer of ncmathsadist, do you think that (in point of view of mathematic), it's a possible justification of the fact that if $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable (i.e. a measurable function).

Comment: Since measurable function are defined a.e. only and since $\{\omega \}$ has measure $0$ (for continuous r.v.), it doesn't make sense to evaluate $X(\omega )$ for a fix $\omega $. And here start the randomness. We are therefore not interested on "which $\omega $ satisfy $a\leq X(\omega )\leq b$" (since for a fixed $\omega $, we don't know $X(\omega )$) but rather on "What proportion of $\omega $ satisfy $a\leq X(\omega )\leq b$". And after, why not introduce Tyche for more elementary example :-) Do you think it make sense ? Thanks a lot for your time, it helps a lot.

Comment: Of your I understand if you don't answer, but I would appreciate a lot to have your opinion on this previous question :). Have a nice sunday.